# Error login PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un login usando PHP, MYSQL.

Siempre me manda el mensaje de error aun que el usuario si exista en la base de datos.

Este es el codigo donde realizo la consulta

```
<?php
   require "lib/cnx.php";  
    if($_POST){
$nombre = $_POST['txtusuario'];
$pass = $_POST['txtpassword'];


$consulta = "SELECT * FROM us WHERE nombre = '".$nombre."'
and pass='".$pass."'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta)  or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); 


if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Bienvendio");
    window.location.href="start.php";
    </script>';
}else{
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Error");
    window.location.href="index.html";
    </script>';
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
}
```

Hice una prueba haciendo una pagina de registro para ver si insertaba correctamente los datos o no si no hacia bien la conexion a la base de datos pero el registro si lo hace correctamente.

Espero me puedan resolver de esta duda

Comment: Prueba 1º los datos a nivel de PHP de este modo: `if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta)) { $datos= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); } else { $datos=r mysqli_error($mysqli); } var_dump($datos);` Puede que haya algún error en la consulta. Tampoco me convence tu uso del `or` ni abusar tanto de una misma variable como haces con `$resultado`.

Comment: @A.Cedano me manda la consulta array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "admin" ["nombre"]=> string(5) "admin" [1]=> string(5) "admin" ["pass"]=> string(5) "admin" } no me manda ningun error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la segunda asignación del $resultado:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consulta)  or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){
```

la función mysqli_fetch_array http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php te devuelve en $resultado el array **final** de la consulta. Mysqli_num_rows http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php requiere como parametro el **primer** $resultado (el de mysqli_query). Esa función te esta devolviendo 0.

Para ver cuantas filas tiene ese ultimo `$resultado`, te basta con comprobar:

```
if(count($resultado)>0){
```